# Cannot find module 'mongoose' even though it exists

Tags: node.js, mongoose, node-modules

I am trying to run my node file but it gives me an error saying "Cannot find module 'mongoose'". I checked, I have mongoose in the node modules folder already. I have already tried deleting node module, packagelock.json and running npm install. I also tried downloading mongoose globally and linking them. None of them seem to work.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Ahsim Shakya/Desktop/LoginPage/database/models/userDetails.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Ahsim Shakya/Desktop/LoginPage/server/server.js:11:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

Comment: Did you imported it in userDetails.js file? like const mongoose = require("mongoose");

Comment: Can you add a your code with the model definition

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes i added that

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue and this worked for me

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install -g npm@latest
npm i core-util-is
```